# Porque no logro que se me apliquen los media queries?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

No logro hacer que mis media queries se apliquen, siendo que ya he realizado una pagina aplicando asi mismo y si me funciona, no tengo idea de porque ahora no. Estoy usando SASS para aplicar los estilos, en la anterior pagina tambien lo use. Este es el codigo del archivo donde tengo las medias:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  /* PAGINA DE INICIO */
  .first-principal,
  span {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }

  .second-principal {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  img-principal {
    width: 200px;
  }

  /* PAGINA DE PROYECTOS */

  .img-proyect {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Este es del archivo donde impoto el sass:

```
@import "_global.scss";
@import "_header.scss";
@import "_index.scss";
@import "_proyects.scss";
@import "_contact.scss";
@import "_footer.scss";
@import "_media.scss";
```

Alguna idea de que puede ser que me este causando esto ? Probe si se veia en google chrome, pero tampoco nada. Solamente un solo estilo se me aplico:

```
span {
        font-size: 3rem;
      }
```

Los demas, nada.

Este es mi html de la pagina de inicio, la cual quiero aplicar los estilos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- BOOTSRAP -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <!-- FUENTES -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inria+Sans&family=Nunito+Sans&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- ICONOS -->
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fc6d6c0790.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>Alejo Hurtado Testa - Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-4">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"
            ><img src="imgs/2-solologo.png" alt="Logo"
          /></a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="45"
              height="45"
              fill="currentColor"
              class="bi bi-list"
              viewBox="0 0 16 16"
            >
              <path
                fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html"
                  >Home</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="pages/proyects.html">proyectos</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="pages/contact.html">contacto</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="principal">
        <div>
          <h1 class="first-principal">alejo hurt<span>ado testa</span></h1>
          <h2 class="second-principal">front-end developer.</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img
            src="imgs/development-g9f72eb99f_1280.png"
            alt="Front-End Developer"
            class="img-principal"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="pie-pagina">
      <div class="group-1 row">
        <div class="box col-md-4">
          <figure class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <a href="index.html"
              ><img src="imgs/2-recortada.png" alt="Logo propio"
            /></a>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="box col-md-4">
          <h3 class="title-about-footer">sobre mi</h3>
          <p>
            Soy de Tío Pujio - Córdoba - Argentina. Me considero un
            desarrollador wed con buen potencial. Soy una persona que aprende
            rápido, responsable, apasionado por lo que hago y con muchas ganas
            de seguir formándome y mejorando como persona. Actualmente estoy
            estudiando Técnico Superior en Programación, a la par de eso,
            realizó cursos en Udemy o CoderHouse. Mi objetivo es poder seguir
            formándome en esta área para poder cumplir con las expectativas del
            mercado laboral.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box col-md-4">
          <h4 class="title-about-footer">seguime en:</h4>
          <div class="social-media">
            <a
              href="https://www.instagram.com/alejohurtadotest/?next=%2F"
              class="fa-brands fa-instagram d-inline-block"
              target="_blank"
            ></a>
            <a
              href="https://twitter.com/testa_alejo"
              class="fa-brands fa-twitter d-inline-block"
              target="_blank"
            ></a>
            <a
              href="https://github.com/Alejo-Hurtado-Testa"
              class="fa-brands fa-github d-inline-block"
              target="_blank"
            ></a>
            <a
              href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alejo-hurtado-testa-53b14a216/"
              class="fa-brands fa-linkedin d-inline-block"
              target="_blank"
            ></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group-2">
        <small
          >&copy; 2023 Alejo Hurtado Testa - Todos los derechos estan
          reservados.</small
        >
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ya lo solucione :)

Comment: Podrías incluir algo más de info, por favor? Digamos, la página sobre la que se aplican esos estilos, el nombre del CSS que nos estás mostrando y la forma como estás validando qué estilos aplica

Comment: Comparte tu html, para verificar que estés incluyendo los meta tags.

Comment: Ahí edite mi pregunta y puse el html, el nombre del CSS es style, compilo el sass en el cual estoy trabajando y esa compilación se transforma en el CSS. Espero ahora se entienda un poquito mejor